# where this LocalizationService class should be in DDD with Onion Architecture

Tags: domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I'm trying to learn DDD with Onion Architecture but I faced a problem
My application should support localization over labels, enums, validation messages and some data in some entities (e.g. Item.ItemName)
So, it's obvious that the localization process relates to the domain and the ui
And this localization service should also support caching
Now I'm confused where should I put this class

Comment: Any help ?  This problem is so confusing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't do localization with DDD approach yet, but I'll try my best to help you.

Localization is a matter of presentation data, I don't think that your domain model should be concerned about it, if its only purpose is presentation.
So how to handle it?

This is how I would do it.

Let's say that client is creating new product. Of course he has to define a name for it.
You want every product name to be translated to different languages. It's your choice how you will do it:

- admin panel for every product
- client has to provide it while creating new product
- dictionary
- mix of all of these

etc. it doesn't really matter.

So in Your `createNewProduct` view you should call product service that will create new product and also call some service that will create translations for that product, but don't save translations in domain entity. In other words you should separate services for handling business logic and for creating translations. Then just link them by productId when presenting.

Comment: So, you say that i should load entity data from two places, one from the domain which will load the whole entity except its localizable properties and the other place will be in application service which will load the localizable properties, Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, but maybe not in an application service, but rather in infrastructure layer. If you will get into performance problem, then you should turn to CQRS approach.